# How to search for file names that contain a number at a specific location in bash

Tags: bash, find

How do I ensure that there is a number after a file name in `find`? Conceptually:

```
find ./directory -name filename{number}.temp
```

If I enter

```
find ./directory -name filename'[0-9]'*.temp
```

it will give me file names of the form `filename'[0-9]'text.temp` as well.

Comment: You were very nearly there but your quotes were the wrong kind and in the wrong place, try `find ./directory -name "filename[0-9]*.temp"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find ./directory -regex '.*/filename[0-9][0-9]*\.temp'
```

Note that `-regex` matches on the whole path, not just the filename.

Answer (score 1):

The older versions of Unix `find` don't do regular expressions or Kornshell style globs. You can use either "?" or "*" in your glob, but that's it. The `find` command on Linux and Macs do have the `-regex` expression.

If your `find` command isn't gnu compatible and doesn't have the `-regex` parameter, you need to pipe the output to `grep`:

```
find ./directory -name 'filename*.temp' | grep '/filename[0-9].temp$'
```

Comment: You mean `grep '/filename[0-9][0-9]*\.temp$'`?

Comment: @RolandIllig - I originally didn't think that was necessary, but you're correct. I could have a directory `foo/filename23.temp/filenamefoo.temp` which would match the `grep`, but not be the right file. I've changed my answer to incorporate your suggestions.